# Why is the flap opening then closing before opening?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use this CodePen (see below) which is an envelope effect.

The top flap  should open when button is clicked, then when the form is sent the top flap should close.

However the issue is: When opening/closing it does a double take. The top flap will open then fold behind the envelope before coming back to the "open" state. The reverse happens when it closes.

How do I remove that open->close->open effect?

Here is the codepen I'm using.

http://codepen.io/permanentinc/pen/muFxK

I believe the culprit is the following piece of code:

```
.close_sesame {
 transform: rotatex(180deg);
 z-index: 9999 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It was the transition-timing-function so I removed the following in bold...

```
.top_flap {
    top: -245px;
  left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 245px;
  width: 800px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 500;
  -moz-perspective: 500;
  -ms-perspective: 500;
  -o-perspective: 500;
  perspective: 500;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom;
  -o-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 500ms 200ms linear;
  transition: all 500ms 200ms linear;

  **Start of Removed**--------------------------------
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 1.3, 0.2, 2.8);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 1.3, 0.2, 2.8);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 1.3, 0.2, 2.8);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 1.3, 0.2, 2.8);
  **End of Removed**---------------------

  z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is the forked codepen with the fix included.

http://codepen.io/SandManMoshi/pen/bVMwNx/